# Returning an array of double values from string

Tags: java

String numbers = ("5,25,77,44,64,8,55,28,86,35");

I would like to return   an array of double values from the string. I am unable to do that successfully with the following code :

```
public static double[] fillArray(String numbers)
{
    String[] answers = numbers.split(",");

    double[] boom = new double[answers.length];

    for (int index = 0; index < answers.length; index++)
    {
        boom[index] = Double.parseDouble(answers[index]);
    }

    return boom;
}
```

The error I get is quite weird...

```
 [De56f047c
```

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java) to see how to simply print out an array.

Answer (score 8):

You're calling `toString()` on an array - and arrays don't override `Object.toString()`. So you get the behaviour from [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Call [`Arrays.toString(double[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29) on the result instead and it will be fine. So this code:

```
double[] array = fillArray("5,25,77,44,64,8,55,28,86,35");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

... gives a result of:

```
[5.0, 25.0, 77.0, 44.0, 64.0, 8.0, 55.0, 28.0, 86.0, 35.0]
```

I really wish `toString()` had been overridden for all arrays. It would make life simpler...

Answer (score 1):

If I follow what you want, you can use this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numbers = ("5,25,77,44,64,8,55,28,86,35");
    List<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (String str : numbers.split(",")) {
        al.add(Double.valueOf(str));
    }
    double[] boom = new double[al.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        boom[i] = al.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boom));
}
```

Output is,

```
[5.0, 25.0, 77.0, 44.0, 64.0, 8.0, 55.0, 28.0, 86.0, 35.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing out the array result properly.

```
double[] array = fillArray("5,25,77,44,64,8,55,28,86,35");
```

You probably did this:

```
System.out.println(array);
```

But you can't do that to print out an array.

The result you got is the

> name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

[Look here to read up on that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

You need to iterate through the array, or use [`Arrays.toString(array[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5b%5d%29)

So for example:

```
for (double d : array) { 
    System.out.print(d + " ");
}
```

Or simply:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```